# Rails 3 - top scoring users query - new approach needed

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

i have two models: users and scores > a user has many scores

the users model contains generic info about the users - name, location etc.
the model scores contains date, score and quality_score values.

what i need is an efficient way to get a list of 20 unique users with the best scores for a given date range. if user 1 has the top 3 scores, i only want their top score against their name and for the user 2 to their best score agains their name. (my test data has 000s of users and 000000s of scores).

I managed to make this work using this (with help from other SO users):

```
@top_users  = User.limit(20).
        select("`users`.*").
        joins(:scores).
        where("datetime_utc >= ? AND datetime_utc <= ?", @utc_time_slot , @utc_time_slot_end).
        group('user_id').
        order("max(quality_score) DESC, max(score) DESC")
```

(thanks to Mario Visic and Chris Bailey) but the query takes an unacceptably long time to run - and i can't help thinking there is a far more efficient way of making this work...

any pointers/ideas? Thanks!

Comment: what's the difference between quality score and score ?

Comment: Its like a speed score and a style score - annoyingly i need both...

Comment: Do you have indexes on those fields in your `scores` table?

Comment: Yes, got indexes on both of those - but they've had (surprisingly) no impact on the performance of the query.

Comment: the fields you should likely index are scores.user_id (the foreign key used by the join) and datetime_utc (used by the where clause)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution is to denormalize a user's best scores into the `users` table, and index that, but if denormalization isn't a practical option for you, I recommend creating an index on `scores.quality_score` and/or `scores.datetime_utc`, depending on which will better reduce the query scope. Then I'd break the query in 2, like this:

```
top_user_scores = Score.limit(20).
    where("datetime_utc >= ? AND datetime_utc <= ?", @utc_time_slot , @utc_time_slot_end).
    group('user_id').
    order("max(quality_score) DESC, max(score) DESC")
User.find(top_user_scores.map(&:user_id))
```

Comment: hi patrick - thanks for this. i'll test it, but just eyeballing, wont this give us the users with the top 20 scores (could be <20 users)?

Comment: oh - and denormalisation, in this case, is off the menu sadly... as you dont know the time range that's going to be asked for...

Comment: @user1051849 - The `group('user_id')` will make sure you only get one row per user